# Split csv file in s3 based on column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I have a larger CSV file which contains approximately 10Million rows and 4 columns,
I have to split these CSV file into multiple CSV files based on a column value(similar to group by)

I think its possible with lambda but not sure if its best possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use native to S3 filtering data (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/selecting-content-from-objects.html)
Amazon S3 Select works on objects stored in CSV, JSON. It is light version of Athena (on one S3 object). I would try this with CLI or SDK (in Console you would be limited to 40 MB of results.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use Lambda but either [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/?nc1=h_ls&whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc) or [AWS EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/de/emr/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc).
Lambda is not build for such memory intense tasks.

Both provide the possibility to develop ETL jobs with Spark or Hadoop.
With EMR you have to manage the cluster by yourself, Glue is completely serverless and you only have to provide your script.